# Fetch records of current month using PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, date-arithmetic

Suppose I have following data in a table

```
id     createdAt
1      2021-02-26T06:29:03.482Z
2      2021-02-27T06:29:03.482Z
3      2021-03-14T06:29:03.482Z
4      2021-03-17T06:29:03.482Z
```

I want data of current month. ie, if I generate report in march, I need to fetch results of march, so we need only current month data from table.

wanted output is

```
id     createdAt  
3      2021-03-14T06:29:03.482Z
4      2021-03-17T06:29:03.482Z
```

Anyone please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the month and year of a date with the current one. But the index by field will not be used, you can build a separate index by year and month for this.

```
select *
from your_table
where extract(YEAR FROM createdAt) = extract(YEAR FROM now())
      and extract(MONTH FROM createdAt) = extract(MONTH FROM now())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `date_trunc()`:

```
select *
from the_table
where date_trunc('month', createdat) = date_trunc('month', current_timestamp);
```

`date_trunc('month', ...)` returns the first day of the month.

However, the above is not able to make use of an index on `createdat`. To improve performance, use a range query:

```
select *
from the_table
where createdat >= date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)
  and createdat < date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) + interval '1 month'
```

The expression `date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) + interval '1 month'` returns the start of the *next* month (that's way this is compared with `<`)